# Extracting messages with react-intl and babel-plugin-formatjs doesn't work when default messages are variables

Tags: reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

In a CRA project, I am trying to use react-intl and extract all the messages used in all the `<FormattedMessage />` components following the [documentation](https://formatjs.io/docs/getting-started/message-extraction), with babel-plugin-formatjs and @formatjs/cli . The extraction works basically, but the generated json file is lacking details.

Instead of looking like this:

```
{
  "hak27d": {
    "defaultMessage": "Control Panel",
  },
  "haqsd": {
    "defaultMessage": "Delete user {name}",
  },
}
```

The defaultMessage fields are missing **when they are originally created with variables**:

```
  "button-text": {
  },
```

For example:

```
 <h1>
  <FormattedMessage
   id="roi-carousel-title"
   defaultMessage={messages.title}
  />
</h1>
```

**Any idea how to fix this?**

---

More details:

Following the documentation,

1. I added a babel.config.json file with the content:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "formatjs",
      {
        "idInterpolationPattern": "[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]",
        "ast": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

2. I added a script to the scripts in package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     ...
    "extract": "formatjs extract"
  }
}
```

3. I am executing the script as follows:

```
npm run extract -- 'src/**/*.ts*' --ignore='**/*.d.ts' --out-file lang/en.json --id-interpolation-pattern '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]'
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/optimistic-davinci-4f7h4m?file=%2Flang%2Fen.json%3A1%2C1) replicating the problem - well, sort of; actually, in the sandbox the extraction fails completely - an empty object is created in the en.json file.

*At the sandbox, one should use

```
yarn extract -- 'src/**/*.ts*' --ignore='**/*.d.ts' --out-file lang/en.json --id-interpolation-pattern '[sha512:contenthash:base64:6]'
```